# A collection of any type

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I am working on a project that will generate an Excel file from data presented. The `Book` class has multiple `Sheet` classes, and each `Sheet` class contains a list of objects. However, the different sheets may have different types of data.

I.e. Sheet one may be a `List<Dog>` and Sheet two may be a `List<Planet>`.

The idea is to get different result sets from EF, create a new book, add a Sheet for each result set, and then have the app create the Excel file.

Using generics (which I am quite new to) is giving me some problems.

```
public class Book
{
    public List<Sheet> Sheets { get; set; }
}

public class Sheet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<T> Data { get; set; }
}
```

This does not work, because "T could not be found", so I change Sheets

```
public class Sheet<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<T> Data { get; set; }
}
```

But then Book needs to know about T, which makes my list of Sheet only one type.

I tried the interface route, and added the two properties to the interface, but that (again) caused me to have to have to supply T.

```
public interface ISheet
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<T> Data { get; set; }
}
```

I feel certain that I am missing something obvious and I am making this too complex.

Thanks

[Edit : in the one example I used '`List<Book>`', but I realised that is confusing, so I changed it to '`List<Planet>`']

Comment: Weird question => Does Dog and Book have something properties in common?

Comment: The type system and the errors you're getting are trying to save you from yourself. Even if your first attempt `Book` and `Sheet` had worked, there's no way for you to write *type safe* code that iterates `Sheets` and accesses the `Data` property of each.

Comment: Let's say you get this working, how would you expect to use this in code? (or another way of saying that, what Damien said!)

Comment: @CodeNotFound, nope. They can be anything.

Comment: @AtronSeige So create two separate properties. One for List<Dog> and another one for List<Book>. Make you design maintenable.

Comment: @AtronSeige: then you only have `Object` which is still better than nothing, you could cast it or use `ToString`.

Comment: @CodeNotFound, not feasible, as this can be any type, from many systems. Hopefully even working with anonymous types.

Comment: Thanks TimSchmelter and Damien_The_Unbeliever. I will attempt with Object and see if I get what I hope to achieve

Comment: Basically, when you're *authoring* generic code, you don't know what type you'll be working with but are able to apply constraints. When you're *consuming* generic code (writing code that uses existing generic types/methods), you *do* need to know the concrete types you're working with (unless your code is, itself, generic). You're trying to *consume* generic classes whilst still not knowing the concrete types and can't be generic yourself.

Comment: @AtronSeige it is very unlikely that this approach may help you. but is there any chances that  `List<ObjTypeWrapper>` (where `ObjTypeWrapper` is class with `Object` and `Type` property)\ help you with this "A collection of any type" requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine Generic with inheritance a simple solution may be:

```
public class Book
{
    public List<Sheet> Sheets { get; set; }
}

//Use sheet as a base class for specific Sheet
public abstract class Sheet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract IList Data { get; }
}

//Use the generic class to unify sheet management
public class SheetTyped<T> : Sheet
{        
    private List<T> _data { get; set; }
    public override IList Data { get { return _data; } }

    public SheetTyped(string sheetName, List<T> lData)
    {
        _data = lData;
        Name = sheetName;
    }
}
```

Of course you must use at least one factory method that knows the type of sheet to create and looks like to:

```
public class Dog {
   string Name;
   public Dog(string name) { Name = name ; }
}
public class Cat {
   string Name;
   public Cat(string name) { Name = name ; }
}

public class test
{
    public Book MyBook ;
    public SheetTyped<Dog> AllMyDog ;
    public SheetTyped<Cat> AllMycat ;

    public void MyTest()
    {
        Dog[] InitDogs = { new Dog("Fuffy")
                         , new Dog("Puffy")
                         , new Dog("Alex") };
        Cat[] InitCats = { new Cat("Romeo")
                         , new Cat("July")
                         , new Cat("Briciola") };

        List<Dog> MyDogList = new List<Dog>(InitDogs);
        List<Cat> MyCatList = new List<Cat>(InitCats);

        AllMyDog  = new SheetTyped<Dog>( "My dogs", MyDogList ) ;
        AllMycat  = new SheetTyped<Cat>( "My cats", MyCatList ) ;
        MyBook    = new Book() ;
        MyBook.Sheets = new List<Sheet>(2);
        MyBook.Sheets[0] = AllMyDog  ;
        MyBook.Sheets[1] = AllMycat  ;
    }
}
```

I think that works.
Let me know if it's useful for you.
Bye